# $.parseXML() is not working with xml string without root node

Tags: jquery, xml

Below is my code

```
 var str = "<single><n>Q1</n><v></v><m></m></single>
            <single><n>Q2</n><v>y</v><m></m></single>
            <single><n>Q3</n><v></v><m>y</m></single>";  
 // ! I gave this string value in three lines just for readability purpose

 var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( str );

 var xml = $(xmlDoc);

 alert(xml.find('single').size());
```

But this is not working, Please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GeWZP/2/) fiddle

Comment: +1 as there's no reason to downvote... especially without an explanation

Comment: I guess it is because "not working" is not a good problem description. The first thing to do when working with Javascript should always be to look in the error console, most often the solution will be in there

Comment: @baliC You are a great commentator :-). But why you are adding and removing comments.. Do you mean to express you do post invalid comments??

Comment: @Pekka Yes, I agree with you. :-) But I am just here to learn things.. In hurry I have posted like that. Now changed Thank you very much for your suggestion and answer as well :-)

Comment: how would you specify a file url that you want to parse with .parseXML;
e-g does this work:  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML('/xml/text.xml');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the browser's error console: You will see something like

> uncaught invalid xml

Adding a [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) will fix it:

```
 <data>
 <single><n>Q1</n><v></v><m></m></single>
 <single><n>Q2</n><v>y</v><m></m></single>
 <single><n>Q3</n><v></v><m>y</m></single>
 </data>
```

Comment: how do I specify the xml url that I need to parse using .parseXML

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeWZP/4/

You are missing your ROOT node. A XML does need a Root node and from that ROOT node you can generate child nodes.

```
var str = "<root>
               <single><n>Q1</n><v></v><m></m></single>
               <single><n>Q2</n><v>y</v><m></m></single>
               <single><n>Q3</n><v></v><m>y</m></single>
           </root>";
```